# Restart a Discord Bot

Tags: discord

I have created a Discord bot then started it already without commands, I have to restart it because I edited the codes with commands, how do you restart it with the terminal in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 0):

Hello you shuld do this:
Ctrl + c to close the current running thing.
Then write node + (your file name)+.js and your new code will running.
You can mark my reply as the solution and get this thread closed.
If it work.